# React - webpack hmr

Tags: webpack-dev-server, browser-sync

tinkering with webpack and associated stuff for the first time.  i am trying to combine the benefits of webpack-dev-server and browser-sync to make it so when i update a react component my browser doesn't reload, it simply uses hot module replacement.  there are plenty of boilerplates i guess, but i am starting from scratch.

im to the point where HMR is on and listening for changes.  i edit a component and it receives the change and says App is up to date.  But the view doesn't change an a few seconds later i get a Web Socket error.
[image: error]

if that is hard to read it basically says Web Socket error, socket closed before completing handshake...

my webpack config

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'src');
const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'dist');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        `${SRC_DIR}/index.js`
    ],
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR,
        publicPath: '',
        filename: 'bundle.js'

    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader','sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
                include: SRC_DIR
            }
            ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            template: require('html-webpack-template'),
            appMountId: 'root',
            devServer: '0.0.0.0' +':'+ 8081,
            title: "Webpack 4 React"
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: process.env.IP,
            port: process.env.PORT,
            //server: { baseDir: ['dist'] },
            ui: {
                port: 8082
            },
            proxy: process.env.IP +':'+ 8081
        },
        {
            reload: false
        }
        )
        ],

    devtool: 'source-map',

    devServer: {
        publicPath:'',
        host: process.env.IP,
        port: 8081,
        hot: true
    }
};
```

babel portion of package.json

```
  "babel": {
    "presets":["es2015","react"],
    "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

many moving pieces and approaches make this a tough thing to pin down.  but i feel like even if this isn't the most optimal setup, i am close to getting it to work.  after all, my browser-sync page is getting the HMR json from the WDS.  maybe i have just missed something simple.  one strange thing is the concept of public path for example, i can't seem to get that to work unless it is an empty string. like i said this is day one with webpack, i still have a lot to learn here. thanks.

i should probably add my index.js, the entry point for webpack

```
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './Components/App';
import './styles.scss';

const root = document.getElementById("root");
//ReactDOM.render(<App/>,root);

const render = Component =>
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    root
  );

render(App);

if (module.hot) module.hot.accept('./Components/App', () => render(App));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up I have got things working, with just minor changes to the code above.  First thing is in `index.js`.  I was missing a declaration for the new updated component.  So:

```
if (module.hot) module.hot.accept('./Components/App', () => render(App));
```

Is replaced with the following:

```
if (module.hot) module.hot.accept('./Components/App', () => {
  const newApp = require("./Components/App").default;
  render(newApp);
});
```

Since I am using React and react-hot-loader, the magic is done and my changes take effect without a page reload and thus losing state.  One caveat I have found is that if my changes involve creating a constructor and state for a component that will cause a page reload, but that makes sense.

I also had to change the way I dealt with `scss` files.  I was using the `ExtractTextPlugin`.  After some research I found that this is better for production, and doesn't support HMR.  That is straight from Webpack Docs.  So I had to alter my `webpack.config.js`.  I comment out the use of the plugin in my plugins section and change my `scss` rule to the following.

```
{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },{
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },{
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                    ]
                /* no HMR better for production
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader','sass-loader']
                })*/
            },
```

The above is the entire `scss` rule with my old stuff just commented out so I can add it to a webpack production config file in the future.  Now it is on the next, bringing in redux and react router.